# Using the Magento Catalog Widget options for my own Widget

Tags: magento2.3, backend, widgets

The widget I'm building shows 4 products on the homepage. These products are required to be configurable (Example: multiple colors), have a custom cache timeout, and easily selectable in the options panel. I think the Catalog Widget options might be perfect for that.

How would I be able to use my own logic + the Catalog Widget options in one widget?

Right now I'm using a custom made ProductChooser but the code for that is outdated. The only part I'm still using is the `Vendor\Module\Block\Widget\FeaturedProducts` Block.

**widget.xml**

```
<widget id="featured_products" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Widget\FeaturedProducts"
            is_email_compatible="false" placeholder_image="Magento_Cms::images/widget_block.png">
        <label>Homepage: Featured products</label>
        <description>Featured products</description>

        <parameters>
            <parameter name="title_suffix" xsi:type="text" visible="true" required="true">
                <label>Titel (suffix)</label>
            </parameter>

            <parameter name="product_ids" visible="true" required="true" xsi:type="block">
                <label>Producten</label>
                <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\ProductChooser">
                    <data>
                        <item name="button" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="open" xsi:type="string">Selecteer producten...</item>
                        </item>
                    </data>
                </block>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
```

If you have any suggestions or criticism, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I fixed the problem by copy & pasting certain methods(functions) from the class I was trying to use into our class. Probably not the best solution but for now the only one we have.